# python extracting values from lists inside a list

Tags: python, list, selenium-webdriver

With Selenium Webdriver I search for input value in google search. Then take links one by one, run them and take emails from each URL.

`[[], [], [], [], ['info@neurotechnology.com', 'support@neurotechnology.com', 'support@neurotechnology.com'], ['info@neurotechnology.com', 'support@neurotechnology.com', 'support@neurotechnology.com'], ['info@himalayakarya.com', 'info@himalayakarya.com'], ['info@himalayakarya.com', 'info@himalayakarya.com'], ['sales@obejor.com', 'sales@obejor.com'], ['sales@obejor.com', 'sales@obejor.com'], [], [], ['507c10c65fb14333bfa540a7cfb4b543@o417096.ingest.sentry.io'], ['507c10c65fb14333bfa540a7cfb4b543@o417096.ingest.sentry.io'], ['hello@paykobo.com'], ['hello@paykobo.com'], ['customercare@indiamart.com'], ['customercare@indiamart.com'], [], [], [], []] [[], ['info@neurotechnology.com', 'support@neurotechnology.com', 'support@neurotechnology.com'], ['info@himalayakarya.com', 'info@himalayakarya.com'], ['sales@obejor.com', 'sales@obejor.com'], ['507c10c65fb14333bfa540a7cfb4b543@o417096.ingest.sentry.io'], ['hello@paykobo.com'], ['customercare@indiamart.com']]`

The result is lists of lists. I need to take lists out of them to be `str` values inside a list.

```
#open google
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.headless = False
chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
# options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=chrome_options)
driver.get('https://www.google.com/')

#paste - write name
#var_inp=input('Write the name to search:')
var_inp='dermalog lf10'
#search for image
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "q"))).send_keys(var_inp+Keys.RETURN)
#find first 10 companies
res_lst=[]
res=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.TAG_NAME,'cite')))
print(len(res))
for r in res:
    res_lst.append(driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].firstChild.textContent;", r))

print(res_lst)

#take email addresses from company
import re
emails_lst=[]
for i in range(len(res_lst)):
    driver.get(res_lst[i])
    email_pattern = r"[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z|a-z]{2,4}"
    html = driver.page_source
    emails = re.findall(email_pattern, html)
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    print(emails)
    emails_lst.append(emails)

print(emails_lst)
no_duplicates=[x for n, x in enumerate(emails_lst) if x not in emails_lst[:n]]
print(no_duplicates)
driver.close()
#send email
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flatten an irregular (arbitrarily nested) list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-arbitrarily-nested-list-of-lists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a *list* out of a *list of lists* you can use the following logic:

```
list = [['info@neurotechnology.com', 'support@neurotechnology.com', 'support@neurotechnology.com'], ['info@neurotechnology.com', 'support@neurotechnology.com', 'support@neurotechnology.com'], ['info@himalayakarya.com', 'info@himalayakarya.com'], ['info@himalayakarya.com', 'info@himalayakarya.com'], ['sales@obejor.com', 'sales@obejor.com'], ['sales@obejor.com', 'sales@obejor.com']]
flat_list = []
for sublist in list:
    for item in sublist:
        flat_list.append(item)
print(flat_list)
```

---

As an alternative you can have nested iterations in a single list comprehension as follows:

```
list = [['info@neurotechnology.com', 'support@neurotechnology.com', 'support@neurotechnology.com'], ['info@neurotechnology.com', 'support@neurotechnology.com', 'support@neurotechnology.com'], ['info@himalayakarya.com', 'info@himalayakarya.com'], ['info@himalayakarya.com', 'info@himalayakarya.com'], ['sales@obejor.com', 'sales@obejor.com'], ['sales@obejor.com', 'sales@obejor.com']]
flatened_list = [item for sublist in list for item in sublist]
print(flatened_list)
```

Console output:

```
['info@neurotechnology.com', 'support@neurotechnology.com', 'support@neurotechnology.com', 'info@neurotechnology.com', 'support@neurotechnology.com', 'support@neurotechnology.com', 'info@himalayakarya.com', 'info@himalayakarya.com', 'info@himalayakarya.com', 'info@himalayakarya.com', 'sales@obejor.com', 'sales@obejor.com', 'sales@obejor.com', 'sales@obejor.com']
```

Comment: is it, `list comprehension` advanced level? Looking for substring inside list with nested loop? Hard to absorb...

Comment: @xlmaster Updated with the actual logic.